# PHP Directory Read, Count & Filesize

Tags: php, count, directory, filesize

I have a mostly-working piece of code to read a directory, output each folder name and count the files and the total size of the files in that directory. But for some reason it is skipping over some folders and not inserting the information into my database.

My Code:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('E:/')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != '$RECYCLE.BIN' && $entry != 'System Volume Information') {
        $exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comics WHERE title LIKE '".$entry."%'");
        $exists1 = mysql_num_rows($exists);
            if ($exists1 != 1) {
            $directory = "E:/".$entry;
            $filecount = count(glob($directory."/"."*.*"));
            $size = 0; 
            $d = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( 
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory),  
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST 
            ); 

            foreach($d as $file){ 
            $size += $file->getSize(); 
            } 

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO comics (title, pages, size, storage_id) VALUES ('".$entry."\n', '".$filecount."', '".number_format($size/1048576, 2)."', '2')");
                print "<li>Inserted <b>".$entry."</b> With A File Count Of <b>".$filecount."</b> & A Total Size Of <b>".number_format($size/1048576, 2)."</b> MB.</li>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It skips over simple folder name like `Beyond The Wall of Sleep` and does not add them to the database although it does echo the output as if it did input it into the database. Where am I going wrong?

Output Example (Folders not added but they still get listed):

```
•Inserted Ay Papi 1 With A File Count Of 22 & A Total Size Of 2.59 MB.
•Inserted Beyond The Wall of Sleep With A File Count Of 26 & A Total Size Of 14.92 MB.
•Inserted Fall of Cthulhu With A File Count Of 22 & A Total Size Of 7.57 MB.
•Inserted Heavy Metal - Fantasy Special With A File Count Of 98 & A Total Size Of 49.66 MB.
```

Comment: Hope you don't have any files named `'; DROP TABLES; --` (i.e. escape your database inputs)

Comment: no its jsut a local project im workin on and theres no drop files named :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the entry to the DB:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comics
        (title, pages, size, storage_id)
        VALUES ('".$entry."\n', '".$filecount."', '".number_format($size/1048576, 2)."', '2')";
mysql_query($sql);
print "<li>$sql</li>";
```

Then get the string you are trying to input into MySQL, go to phpmyadmin or to terminal mysql, and try to insert that query. You will get mysql error.

Another way to debug it would be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comics
        (title, pages, size, storage_id)
        VALUES ('".$entry."\n', '".$filecount."', '".number_format($size/1048576, 2)."', '2')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
print "<li>$sql</li>";
if (!$res)
{
  echo "Mysql Error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: thank you that helps out alot. now what would be a better way to check if it exists?

Comment: what do you want to check if exists: if you already have an entry in the database? [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) would be the best, but you need to create an unique index/primary key on entry.

Comment: i want to check if the `title` exists, as the first query in my code suggests, but it does't return a 1 to show that it exists, and i have the `title` set as a unique key. on duplicate update wont really work cuz i dont want to update anything just skip the insert query.

Comment: then if you want to skip [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is the command you're looking for

Comment: found it! `if ($exists1 != 1) {` needed to be changed to `if ($exists1 == 0) {` and it works now. thank you for your time sir :D

Comment: You're welcome. Sure that would do. Another way would be using [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function, and then the same check you are doing.